# How to get full 16 bits range using RasterSymbolizer and ColorMap ramp?

Tags: sld, geos, color-ramp

I am attempting to get the full 16 bits values of my DEM (stored as TIFF files) rendered in WMS tiles (png format).

For this I use GeoServer 2.5 and a RasterSymbolizer with a ColorMap of type "ramp".
Then I used the color "#000000" for the value 0 and the color "#003E80" for 15000. My understanding was that GeoServer will interpolate as such:
1 -> #000001
2 -> #000002
256 -> #000100
15000 -> #003E80
etc...
Instead it looks like it is taking the 16 bits values and divide it by 255 and apply the coefficient to each color. This in effect reduces my height resolution by a big amount!

Is there a way to have the behavior I expected using a ColorMap (or any other sld operator)?

Thanks.